# when location path is empty use onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to use a href and onClick depending on the url.

if `$location.path()` is empty such like `www.mysite.com/` then use onClick function
if url is like `www.mysite.com/about` then use `href="javascript:history.back()"`

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" data-ng-click="vm.backToResult();">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
   Back to Search Results
</a>

vm.backToResult = function() {
    if (!$location.path()) {
       $window.history.back();
    } else {
       $window.location.href = '#!/list-of/options/';
    }
}
```

I think this is working but I have to double click to actually trigger it but not entirely sure to be honest.

Comment: `$window` is just a raw `window` object. angular does nothing with it, while you not decorated it byself

Comment: what should I be using instead of $window?

Comment: `$window.history.back` is ok, may be you want to use `$location.path(newPathHere)` setter for second part.

Comment: I tried $location.href as well but its making to click twice before it trigger.

Comment: Can you make any fiddle with your issue?

Comment: not sure if how I can actually make a fiddle of it though :/

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ucdgpcbL/3/show/light/ find `iframe url` in the dom and open it in new tab. Then fill the input and click the button.. :)